# Rasberry Pi - network boot with old router

Tags: pi-3, networking, boot, raspbian-lite

I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question, but I really don't have a good background knowledge about networking. I did try to google all this stuff, but I simply couldn't find anything specific to my needs, or maybe I am just searching the wrong way because my lack of knowledge.

Anyhow, I am trying to network boot a Raspberry Pi 3 as part of a project at college. I managed to do it on my home network (Raspberry Pi 3 as client and a Raspberry Pi 2 was used as the server), but now the problem is that I can't do that at college because of the network restrictions. I need to find another way.

I have an old router at home and I was wondering can I do all that stuff with the router connected to power and with 2 Ethernet cables so that 2 Raspberries can communicate over that 'offline' router. Is that even possible and if it is, could you please point me in the right direction? As I mentioned before, I couldn't find anything useful so either I am searching for wrong things or it is not possible the way I thought it might be.

Thank you.

Comment: What are the network restrictions at the collage?

Answer (score 0):

Run a dhcpd like dnsmasq, and optionally avahi/bonjour/rendezvous/bleh (mDNS) on your laptop, and connect the PIs to your laptop via a switch. Set the hostnames of your PIs to foo.local and bar.local, they'll be easy to interact with.

Comment: thanks, will try that...but it worked the way I thought it might :)
The only problem is that it worked on my home router even when it's only connected to the power and not on my old router. Don't know why is that.

Comment: Either set static IPs or run dnsmasq. Check that the old router serves DHCP leases.